# 2004 suzuki sv650s alarm connector

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, alarm, connector, sv650

I've recently removed a datatool system 3 alarm and traced all the wires back.  From looking at the Haynes book i appear to be missing 'Alarm connector'  Can anyone explain what this is and what it looks like.

Comment: Is the "alarm connector" supposed to be there per the Haynes manual and isn't, or did you find the alarm connector and have nothing to connect it to? Does the mc start/operate the way it's supposed to?

Comment: Can you provide more details (perhaps a photo) around the 'Alarm Connector' you're seeing? From what I've seen in the official service manual, there is no reference to an alarm. I wouldn't expect an alarm was fitted from the factory.

Comment: I thought I'd let you know I managed to sort it out, I had to join two wires, Black and white to the orange. All good now thanks.